# Avro: SpecificDatumReader/Writer vs ReflectDatumReader/Writer

Tags: java, apache, avro

I have a `byte[]` representation of Avro payload and the schema which is used to encode/decode this payload. There are a few ways to convert this payload to a SpecificRecord, using ReflectDatumReader/Writer and SpecificDatumReader/Writer.

We get an error when we decode using SpecificDatumReader and try to encode a SpecificRecord returned using ReflectDatumReader.

Below is the sample code. Using SpecificDatumReader to get a SpecificRecord (Testing) then using ReflectDatumWriter to attempt to encode it into a byte[], which fails. Finally using a SpecificDatumReader to re-decode it.

```
DatumWriter<Testing> refWriter = new ReflectDatumWriter<>(expectedSchema);
DatumReader<Testing> specReader = new SpecificDatumReader<>(expectedSchema);

// Use SpecificDatumReader to decode to a SpecificRecord
Testing r1 = specReader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(expectedBytePayload, null));

// Use ReflectDatumWriter to write SpecificRecord encode as byte[].
// Note: this step fails
ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
refWriter.write(r1, EncoderFactory.get().binaryEncoder(outStream, null));

// Use SpecificDatumReader to decode to a SpecificRecord
Testing r2 = specReader.read(null, DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(outStream.toByteArray(), null));
```

Error Message:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.ensureBounds(BinaryDecoder.java:473)
    at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readDouble(BinaryDecoder.java:243)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readDouble(ResolvingDecoder.java:190)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:185)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:240)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:230)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:174)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:144)
```

1. Why aren't they interchangeable?
2. When do we use one over another?

Comment: Can you post a code example and post the full exception trace rather than just the message?

Comment: @jkff question is updated with more details.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the details of the error - now I don't see even the error message, the question only says that it "fails". Please include the complete, unedited stacktrace.

Comment: @jkff just edited in an error message. I laid out the questions at the bottom. As mentioned above, both Reflective and Specific datum classes deals with a specific record it would be helpful if you could explain why above example doesn't work. Thanks.